# Do we find out who the Talon of the Court of the Owls is?

Tags: comics, dc, batman

Forgive the rather generic question title, but I was trying to avoid spoilers.

Do we conclusively find out whether

> Lincoln March is Batman's brother?

There are two differing comments in Batman #11, Batman's which points towards it not being him:

[image]

and a comment from the Court to Jarvis which suggests it was him:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe the voice on the phone from the Court of Owls in your second example is insinuating that Thomas Wayne and Lincoln March are the same person. They say, "The school is gone, and a little Wayne, too...", implying that Thomas Wayne is *gone*, not that he was taken by the Court.

At the very end of Batman #11, Alfred and Bruce have a conversation that leaves the question intentionally ambiguous, however. Because "case closed" would just be too convenient:

[image]

So there is no way to know for sure until the next time Lincoln March makes an appearance.

Comment: Good point.  I'd assumed "gone" meant "we've taken control of them", but "gone" meaning "destroyed" makes more sense.

Comment: @dlanod I think the burning building Jarvis Pennyworth is seen escaping from is the school they're referring to, which supports the "gone means destroyed" theory.